# Convert only if criteria are met in the middle of a Join

Tags: sql, performance, join, implicit-conversion

First time posting a question here, but a I am a frequent user of this site, many thanks in advance to this community that has great answers to obscure questions.

Below is a Join that is converting the date on two views that results in ~20 million dates getting reformatted in the "PDR" view.  I can only use the year and month in the Join which is why it is getting converted (I have no option on that part).

I only need to include data in these columns IF Department_Code = 'X' so 90% of the resulting ~500 rows of this final rollup will not having anything in these columns.

I need to make this more efficient, I'd like to say convert the date ONLY if the Department_Code = 'X'

Am I able to add that criteria to a Join?

```
Left Join [dbo].[SLHSV_TM_Pharm_IP_OP_Factor_Rollup] as TMIPOP 
on Left (Convert (varchar, TMIPOP.[Pharm_IPOP_MONTH], 112),6) 
= Left (Convert (varchar, PDR.Payroll_Period_End_Date, 112),6)
```

Comment: which RDBMS?  instead of converting to a varchar you could keep the date conversions as mathematical by joining on both YEAR(date) = YEAR(date) and MONTH() = MONTH().  That might help performance some.  Otherwise you can write a case statement however you want and say when the case statement = 1 then join. E.g. (CASE WHEN department_cod  = 'X' and MONTH(a) = MONTH(b) and YEAR(a) = YEAR(b) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to make this more efficient, I'd like to say convert the date ONLY if the Department_Code = 'X'
>
> Am I able to add that criteria to a Join?

Since the converted dates are used in your [left] join condition, I suppose that avoiding the conversion means rows with `Department_Code` different from `'X'` will (for that reason) not satisfy the join condition.

If the `Department_Code` column is on `SLHSV_TM_Pharm_IP_OP_Factor_Rollup`, then the easiest thing to do would be to write the join condition like so:

```
Left Join [dbo].[SLHSV_TM_Pharm_IP_OP_Factor_Rollup] as TMIPOP 
  on TMIPOP.[Department_Code] = 'X'
  and Left (Convert (varchar, TMIPOP.[Pharm_IPOP_MONTH], 112),6) 
    = Left (Convert (varchar, PDR.Payroll_Period_End_Date, 112),6)
```

Your query planner then *might* avoid evaluating the right side of the `AND` when the left-hand side evaluates to false.  It is allowed to do so, but whether it actually does is implementation dependent.

If you want to be certain, then you can pre-filter the inner-table rows you don't want:

```
Left Join (
    select *
    from [dbo].[SLHSV_TM_Pharm_IP_OP_Factor_Rollup]
    where [Department_Code] = 'X'
  )  as TMIPOP 
  on Left (Convert (varchar, TMIPOP.[Pharm_IPOP_MONTH], 112),6) 
    = Left (Convert (varchar, PDR.Payroll_Period_End_Date, 112),6)
```

If the `Department_Code` column is instead on table `PDR`, then your choices are more limited, but this should work (and an analog should work if that column is on the other table):

```
Left Join [dbo].[SLHSV_TM_Pharm_IP_OP_Factor_Rollup] as TMIPOP 
  on case
    when PDR.[Department_Code] = 'X'
      then Left (Convert (varchar, TMIPOP.[Pharm_IPOP_MONTH], 112),6) 
        = Left (Convert (varchar, PDR.Payroll_Period_End_Date, 112),6)
    else 1 = 0
  end
```

It is conceivable that you would find that last more expensive than just doing all the conversions.  Since performance is apparently your concern here, it is essential to test.  It is also advisable to examine query plans for the options you evaluate, for that might help you find variations that work better.

Comment: It always looks obvious after you see it.  I'm trying this now and letting it run for a bit.   Hope that does it.  I'll reply with the results.  Thanks!
    Left Join (
    select *
    from [dbo].[SLHSV_TM_Pharm_IP_OP_Factor_Rollup]
    where [Department_Code] = 'X'
  )  as TMIPOP